# haproxy rest service fail-over not working

Tags: rest, ssl, haproxy, failover, round-robin

```
frontend localnodes 
bind *:9999 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy.pem
    mode http
default_backend servers
backend servers
mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server A 192.168.101.129:10007 check backup ssl verify none weight 255 #fall 1 rise 1 
    server B 192.168.101.129:10008 check ssl verify none weight 1#fall 1 rise 1
```

I am trying to route Rest services , Now the problem is even if the first server is down the fail-over is not switching to available server.SSL is working fine though.Please tell me where i went wrong.
Thanks